# Jboss EAS + Apache mod_proxy don't load image

Tags: image, apache, web-applications, jboss, apache2

I created a web application that runs on a ubuntu server with JBoss EAS 6.2 and Apache2 with mod_proxy enabled, but when I open the page in the browser, the images do not load.

This is my Apache configs:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ProxyRequests     On
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://pegabuzz.com:8080
    ProxyPassReverse / http://pegabuzz.com:8080

    ServerName pegabuzz.com
    <Location />
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from All
    </Location>    
</VirtualHost>
```

What can I do?

**EDIT 2:**

In the browser console, I get this:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502
>   (Proxy Error)

The path is:

> http://pegabuzz.com/images/pegabuzz_site.jpg

The site URL:

> pegabuzz.com

Comment: Have you tried doing a wget on the server directily to jboss port? Such as: http://pegabuzz.com:8080/images/pegabuzz_site.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks that you have missed the trailing bar after the server port on your ProxyPass and ProxyPassReserves directives.

Try using:

```
ProxyPass / http://pegabuzz.com:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://pegabuzz.com:8080/
```

Because your server return an error during the DNS query:

> Reason: DNS lookup failure for: pegabuzz.com:8080images

Comment: Don't forget to see @endrigoantonini tip. Your image is not available on server that responds at port 8080

Answer (score 0):

Please see what URL it creates for images with help of Firebug plugin in Firefox.

Thing which you need to focus would be missing slashes or path in the URL.

Comment: See my EDIT 2 on the post